# Perl find similar elements from two arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

I would like to retrieve elements from `@amplicon_exon` array that contain similar element (*like*) to `@failedamplicons` array. Each element in `@failedamplicons` is unique and can only match a single element from `@amplicon_exon`. I've tried two for loops but get repeat values. Is there a better way of finding and retrieving similar values from the two arrays?

```
@failedamplicons: example:
OCP1_FGFR3_8.87
OCP1_AR_14.89

@amplicon_exon: example:
TEST_Focus_ERBB2_2:22:ERBB2:GENE_ID=ERBB2;PURPOSE=CNV,Hotspot;CNV_ID=ERBB2;CNV_HS=1
OCP1_FGFR3_8:intron:FGFR3:GENE_ID=FGFR3;PURPOSE=CNV;CNV_ID=FGFR3;CNV_HS=1
OCP1_CDK6_14:intron:CDK6:GENE_ID=CDK6;PURPOSE=CNV;CNV_ID=CDK6;CNV_HS=1
```

Here is two for loop code:

```
my $i = 0;
my $j = 0;

for ( $i = 0; $i < @amplicon_exon; $i++ ) {

    for ( $j = 0; $j < @failedamplicons; $j++ ) {

        my $fail_amp = ( split /\./, $failedamplicons[$j] )[0];

        #print "the failed amp before match is $fail_amp\n";

        if ( index( $amplicon_exon[$i], $fail_amp ) != -1 ) {

            #print "the amplicon exon that matches $amplicon_exon[$i] and sample is $sample_id\n";
            print "the failed amp that matches $fail_amp and sample is $sample_id\n";

            my @parts = split /:/, $amplicon_exon[$i];
            my $exon_amp = $parts[1];

            next unless $parts[3] =~ /Hotspot/;    #includes only Hotspot amplicons
            my $gene_res   = $parts[2];
            my $depth      = ( split /\./, $failedamplicons[$j] )[1];
            my @total_amps = (
                $run_name, $sample_id, $gene_res, $depth, $fail_amp, $run_date, $matrix_status
            );

            my $lines = join "\t", @total_amps;

            push( @finallines, $lines );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a precise criterion for being "_similar_"?

Comment: amplicon_exon element has to contain the full string of failedamplicons element before the ".". for example: `OCP1_FGFR3_8:intron:FGFR3:GENE_ID=FGFR3;PURPOSE=CNV;CNV_ID=FGFR3;CNV_HS=1` contains `OCP1_FGFR3_8` thanks

Comment: @user3781528: I have tidied your Perl code so that I could read it. Please post legible code in the future.

Comment: @user3781528 FYI: a quick way to tidy code is to install Perl::Tidy. It comes with a program, `perltidy`, which you can use to tidy your Perl scripts. https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/lib/Perl/Tidy.pod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) are your friends, as is the idiomatic approach to iterating over a list. Simply iterate over the first array, extract just the part you want to match on (by using `split` to split the element on a `.` character, then taking only the first entry), then using a regex, `grep` for that part of the string in the second array from the beginning of the element up to the `:`:

```
for my $elem (@failedamplicons){
    my $to_match = (split /\./, $elem)[0];
    if (my ($matched) = grep {$_ =~ /^\Q$to_match:/} @amplicon_exon){
        print "$matched\n";
    }        
}
```

Comment: I change the regex so that  meta-characters in `$to_match` are escaped. For more details, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters